# Changing data types in a view not truly changing?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the field "Ticket_Number" whose data type is int.  I need in an outer join to connect this field to the "KeyData" field in another log file table which has the data type "varchar(50)" and sometimes has data with text in it but also has the ticket numbers whose records in this table I need to connect to. I've tried using the "convert" function on the field and even on a subview already pulling only the "numeric-like" data. However, even when I try to connect to a view that's already pulling only the "Numeric-like" data, I continue to get a conversion failed error. What should I do?

Comment: You should start by sharing your view definition, table structure, sample data, the error you're getting, and what your expected results are.

Comment: The following helped me to solve the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984110/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-simple-to-data-type-int

Comment: You could go the other way with it `ON (KeyData = CONVERT(varchar(50), Ticket_Number))`

Answer (score 0):

There may be character value in the VARCHAR field that you are using for join condition .
If you are using SQL server 2012 version, use TRYCONVERT instead of CONVERT function like below.

```
    On Ticket_Number= TRYCONVERT (int,KeyData)
```

Or you can eliminate those non-numeric values also  by adding ISNUMERIC () function in the where clause like below.

```
     Where ISNUMERIC (KeyData)=1
```