# Concat with convert in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to merge 5 columns into one column, sounds simple, but the resultant table where is to be merged that column is a `varchar`, now I have tried  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984110/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-simple-to-data-type-int) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) it does not seem to work.

This is my code:

```
INSERT INTO [RepositoryCoSD].dbo.AnimalProducts
    SELECT 
        [DataSeriesID]
        , concat_ws(CONVERT(INT,
            CASE
               WHEN IsNumeric(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DataSeriesID)) = 1 
                  THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DataSeriesID)
                  ELSE 0 
            END) , '-', '-')
        ,[CommodtiySubCommodityID]
        ,[Commodity]
        ,[SubCommodity]
        ,[SectorID]
        ,[Sector]
        ,[GroupID]
        ,[GroupName]
        ,[StatisticTypeID]
        ,[StatisticType]
        ,[SourceID]
        ,[Source]
        ,[SourceDescription]
        ,[PhysicalAttributeTypeID]
        ,[PhysicalAttributeType]
        ,[PhysicalAttributeDesc]
        ,[UtilizationPracticeID]
        ,[UtilizationPractice]
        ,[ProductionPracticeID]
        ,[ProductionPractice]
        ,[SourceSeriesID]
        ,[TimeID]
        ,[TimeFrequency]
        ,[Date]
        ,[GeographyID]
        ,[GeographyType]
        ,[City]
        ,[County]
        ,[State]
        ,[Region]
        ,[Country]
        ,[UnitID]
        ,[Unit]
        ,[LifecyclePhaseID]
        ,[LifecyclePhaseDescription]
        ,[Value] 
    FROM 
        AnimalProductsCoSD.CoSD.Public_Standard_View
```

I need to merge 5 columns `UnitID, GeoID, TimeID, LifecyclePhaseID` and `DataseriesID`

I am getting this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '-132-' to data type int.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

See the syntax for CONCAT_WS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> CONCAT_WS ( separator, argument1, argument2 [, argumentN]... )

Try re-writing your statement as

```
CONCAT_WS('-',CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),UnitID), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GeoID), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TimeID), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),LifecyclePhaseID), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DataseriesID))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`concat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

```
CONCAT(UnitID, GeoID, TimeID, LifecyclePhaseID, DataseriesID)
```

It will convert its arguments to strings automatically.  This is a bit less messy than using explicit conversions.

You can add other characters too:

CONCAT(UnitID, '-', GeoID, '-', TimeID, '-', LifecyclePhaseID, '-', DataseriesID)

Comment: I did, it did not work, I also want - in between those values

Comment: @BharatRadhakrishnan . . . Then just add hyphens where you want them.

Answer (score 0):

actually the

```
     concat_ws(CONVERT(INT,
                CASE
                WHEN IsNumeric(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DataSeriesID)) = 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),DataSeriesID)
                ELSE 0 END) ,'-','-')
```

line should be first as in the resultant table that merged column has to be first, sorry for the confusion