# How to count the rows of a varchar column and return an integer?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am writing code that needs to recognize if a column is empty or not in my database based on a specific ID. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I've tried:

```
select count(*) as valid from table where id =7PB03150SW
```

But receive the error:

*Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int.*

I also tried:

```
select cast(( select count(*) from table where id = 7PB03150SW)as VarChar(120))
```

But receive the error:

*Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int.*

I want the code to output a single result, the number of times the specific ID appears in the table. The output needs to be able to be read by a c# file.

Comment: can you show us the schema? it sounds like `id` is an int column

Comment: Is your `id` column an `INT`? If so, `7PB03150SW` isn't a valid value for a comparison as it's a string. If the column is actually a `VARCHAR`, you need to wrap `7PB03150SW` in quotes to denote that it's a string: `where id = '7PB03150SW'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984110/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-simple-to-data-type-int I think this is what you need.

Comment: _count(*)_ counts the rows that meet the criteria you specified. Id is a string. You left off the ' ' characters, so SQL will try to convert 7PB03150SW to int. That is causing the error

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the ' '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is almost correct. You just need to add `'` before and after your id value to pass it as a varchar.

So the query should be :
`select count(*) as valid from table where id ='7PB03150SW'`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Declare @ID int = 7PB03150SW
Declare @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
Set @SQL = 'select count(*) from table where id='+cast(@ID AS VARCHAR)
exec(@SQL)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. When answering questions you should add an explaination as to why your code snippet will solve the OP's question. For more info check here: [answer]